# Accessing window.App functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

#### The Problem

I have a pre-made js file (which I don't completely understand) that is being imported to my html page.  This js file defines a function that I would like to be able to call through script blocks in the html page itself.

The function I would like to call is `app.openNav`.  I have tried using a variety of different methods to call this function (`window.App.app.openNav`, `App.app.openNav`, `App.openNav`, `app.openNav`, even `window.openNav`) to no avail.

My failure to call the function through these methods made me think that perhaps I needed to define it outside of the top function (make it global?).  I tried doing that by saying `app.openNav = {};` but that did not work either.

This is in *nav.js*:

```js
(function(window, document, undefined)
{
    window.App = (function()
    {    
        var app = { };

        app.init = function()
        {
            app.openNav = function()
            {
                //open navigation
            };

            // open nav with button
            document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click',app.openNav,false);
        };
        return app;
    })();
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', window.App.init, false);
    }
})(window, window.document);
```

As you can see, I currently have a method of calling `app.openNav` from inside *nav.js* by using `addEventListener` on an html object.  However, I am using an external library ([hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/)) to interpret events which I want to use to open the navigation.

#### Questions

Is it possible to call the `app.openNav` function from outside *nav.js*?
If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: app is effectively private to App - any invocation of methods on the object assigned to App need to be done through App - it should be noted that you've hard-coded an id of 'foo' in your example, so make sure that you actually have an element that will be selected when you're adding the event listener inside your init - run your code in the console and call App.init() to see what it will do

Comment: @kinakuta `app === App`. They're the same object.

Comment: @kinakuta `app` is returned from its function which is immediately invoked and which return value is assigned to `window.App`. Therefore, `window.App` refers to the `app` object. See my demo.

Comment: @kinakuta OP wants to know how to access the `app.openNav` function from a different script. Since, `app` is assigned to `App`, that function can be accessed via `App.openNav`. This answers OP's question. You didn't mention this solution in your initial comment, so I assumed you didn't understand this.

Comment: @kinakuta You fail to see that `app` is exactly the same as `App`. They're one and the same object. The local `app` name is just used out of convenience while constructing the object. (jQuery is doing the same thing it it's code, btw). Therefore, `app` being "not in scope" is irrelevant here (and misleading, IMO). The was this pattern is supposed to be used is, methods are defined on `app` and then invoked on `App`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code, it is accessible as `App.openNav`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/6N3dZ/ (Wait 2 seconds for the alert to show up.)